# $X_i$ are Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,...,X_k$, $k\geq 2$, be independent random variables, each having the same positive and differentiable density function $f$. Further suppose $\prod_{j=1}^k f(x_j)$ depends only on $x_1^2+...+x_k^2$. Then there is a $\sigma>0$ such that $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}, \,\,\, (x\in \Bbb{R}).$$

**My attempt:** We can get a differential equation the following way:

We can write $\prod_{j=1}^k f(x_j)=g(x_1^2+...+x_k^2)$ for some function $g$. Taking logarithms yields $$\sum_{j=1}^k \log( f(x_j)) = \log( g(x_1^2+...+x_k^2)).$$
Then we can take partial derivatives, which gives:

$$\frac{f'(x_j)}{f(x_j)} = 2x_j \frac{g'(x_1^2+...+x_k^2)}{g(x_1^2+...+x_k^2)}.$$

I don't know how to proceed, or if this is useful. I haven't used the independence yet.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Duplicate of a very recent question (without the differentiability hypothesis).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the question on here. Can you link me? $f$ is assumed to be differentiable

Answer (score 0):

Consider f'($x_j$)/$2xf(x_j)$= g'($x_1$,$x_2$...$x_k$)/g'($x_1$,$x_2$...$x_k$).
LHS depends only on $x_j$ but RHS on all the k variables. So, actually LHS is identical for all values of $x_j$.

Put LHS= c (constant). solve the differential equation, voila!

Comment: I don't have much experience with differential equations. How do I solve this one: $$c = \frac{g'(x_1^2 +...+x_k^2)}{g(x_1^2+...+x_k^2}$$?

Comment: Solve the LHS= c, not RHS= c

Comment: I see. But where did we use independence of the $X_i$ then?